# java code to run a method when a searchview query is submitted

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `searchView` called `mySearchView`.

How can I run a method when the search is sent?

This method will also use the text from the `searchView`.

I have the xml for the activity, `searchView` and a java file with a `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, `SearchView.OnCloseListener` and in its override method you'll get the text you want which is written in searchview. And in its `onQueryTextSubmit` method you can call your method. And in its `onClose` method you can do anything you want to do when your `searchview` is closed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements 
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(MainActivity.this);
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit : " + query);
        //do something you submit your query
        //call your method;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onQueryTextChange : " + newText);
        //do something when text is changed
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onClose");
        //do something you want to do when searchview is closed
        return false;
    }
}
```